# Xcode 10 build fail rm permission denied in /bin/sh/

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode10, macos-mojave

I recently update my system to
**Xcode: 10

OSX : Mojave 10.14**

For few days my iOS development works fine, but suddenly start facing following issues.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Appsee.framework/Appsee
 Referenced from: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2223E5BD-215F-48D7-8649-2D63ECBAE2B6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59E09AD0-ADAB-4221-A334-70F71DC6AC0B/MyApp.app/MyApp
 Reason: image not found
```

But this issue was fixed by changing `Xcode`->`File`->`Workspace Setting`->`Build Setting`->`Legacy Build Setting`

Then I getting permission denied error for `rm` command in one of shell script used while building the target.

[image: xcode build error]

```
Showing All Messages
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Common: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/USGlobals.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRKeepAliveData.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFSOAPClient.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRHubRegistrationData.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRHubProxy.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CMSeatMapWingView.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRHubProxyInterface.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRLog.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GrafanaClient.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/NSObject+SRJSON.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRHubConnectionInterface.h: Permission denied
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRHubInvocation.h: Permission denied        
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFIncrementalStoreHTTPClient.h: Permission denied        
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRHubConnection.h: Permission denied        
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRLongPollingTransport.h: Permission denied        
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ApplicationBuildConfiguration.h: Permission denied        
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ServiceConfiguration.h: Permission denied        
rm: /Users/a.b.ak1b/Documents/work/iOS-App-1/Library/Common/../Vendor/Common.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SRConnectionInterface.h: Permission denied
```

**For the time-being I need to build the target using `sudo xcodebuild`. Not found any way to trigger build using xcode to avoid this error.**

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues here:

1. Why shell script is throwing error?

This is because of MacOS Mojave privacy protection.
You need to give permission to XCode to have Full Disk Access. You can do this in System Preferences->Security&Privacy [image]

2. XCode 10 uses a [new build system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10).

> Xcode 10 uses a new build system. The new build system provides
>   improved reliability and build performance, and it catches project
>   configuration problems that the legacy build system does not.

I am not sure why the error happened after few days but perhaps it has to do with changes in ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS. I am not sure about this, but you can try adding Appsee.framework as an embedded binary in Target-> General-> Embedded Binaries

Comment: thanks for answer, problem has been solved. This setting was not worked but it help me to find out the solution. My code was in Document folder. I have put it in some other folder then it works. It was due to permission issues in new OSX